# ¿Se puede usar mayúscula después de dos puntos?

Tags: ortografía, puntuación, uso-de-mayúsculas

Yo siempre he usado minúscula después de dos puntos. No sé si porque me lo enseñaron o sólo por costumbre.

Sin embargo, estaba leyendo la entrada de [*constituyente*](https://dle.rae.es/constituyente) en el diccionario de la RAE (a propósito de la situación política chilena, para ver si era un neologismo o una palabra registrada), y encontré esto:

> **2.** adj. Dicho de las Cortes o de otras cámaras o asambleas: Convocadas para elaborar o reformar la Constitución del Estado. U. t. c. s.

Dudo mucho que la RAE esté equivocada, pero no sé por qué se usa mayúscula en *Convocadas*. ¿Me pueden explicar si hay una regla para eso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mi respuesta está basada en una síntesis propia de la Ortografía de la lengua española de la RAE (2011):

[image]
[image]

El caso en cuestión no se corresponde exactamente con ninguno de los mencionados. Es una definición introducida por una aclaración. Si la aclaración no estuviera, sin duda se usaría la mayúscula, como en todas las demás entradas. Podría no haberse usado dos puntos y encerrado la aclaración entre paréntesis:

(Dicho de las Cortes o de otras cámaras o asambleas) Convocadas para elaborar o reformar la Constitución del Estado.

Mi interpretación (que agregaré a mi síntesis) es que "Dicho de las Cortes o de otras cámaras o asambleas" tiene valor metatextual respecto de "Convocadas ...", por lo que la definición se escribe con mayúscula por ser la primera frase del renglón con valor textual.

Comment: Respuesta concisa, que apunta directamente al problema tratado.

Comment: Creo que tu explicación es correcta. Sin embargo, no estoy de acuerdo con esta decisión ortográfica, pues, para ser coherentes, deberíamos usar mayúscula después de la coma que marca hipérbaton a principio de oración.

Answer (score 0):

En la «Ortografía de la lengua española» de 2010, (https://www.rae.es/obras-academicas/ortografia/ortografia-2010), última de las ortografías académicas publicadas, en su capitulo IV "El uso de las letras mayúsculas y minúsculas", FUNCIONES Y USOS DE LA MAYÚSCULA" hallamos el apartado 4.1 "PARA DELIMITAR LAS UNIDADES TEXTUALES PRINCIPALES" y en su interior en el 4.1.1.4, en su párrafo **c)** leemos lo siguiente:

> c) **Tras los dos puntos** que cierran los epígrafes o subtítulos **de un** libro o **documento**, o los elementos de una enumeración en forma de lista, **cuando el texto explicativo que los sigue comienza en la misma línea**:
>
> **La arquitectura egipcia: El elemento más característico de la arquitectura egipcia son las pirámides, construcciones funerarias que…**
>
> En esa región se crían gran variedad de setas:
>
> - Trompeta de los muertos: Se trata de una seta comestible, con
>   sombrero en forma de trompeta, especialmente adecuada para…
> - Rebozuelo: Es una seta muy fácil de reconocer, de color amarillo o anaranjado…

**Fuente:** *Ortografía de la lengua española. (RAE y ASALE, Espasa, 2010)*. *pag. 461*

Un extracto, podemos descargarlo en el sitio utilizado por la propia RAE para informar y aclarar dudas. RAEinforma (RAE);

http://ow.ly/d/6MSR

---

Sin duda aquí se encuentra la razón por la que detrás de los dos puntos, aparece la palabra en mayúscula, **ya que el texto explicativo que los sigue comienza en la misma línea**.

---

*Constituyente*

***Dicho de las Cortes o de otras cámaras o asambleas: Convocadas para elaborar o reformar la Constitución del Estado***

Comment: Útil tu información, muchas gracias. Sin embargo, no es tan obvio que en este caso lo que viene después de los dos puntos sea una oración completa. (A lo mejor sí lo es, pero no llega tan lejos mi gramática).